# opencv4.0.1 for android Stitcher module not found

Tags: android, opencv

I am using opencv4.0.1 code, using below steps to build out the sdk:

```
cd opencv-master

mkdir build
cd build

export ANDROID_SDK=~/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_NDK=~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle
export PATH=/usr/local/opt/ccache/libexec:$PATH
../opencv-master/platforms/android/build_sdk.py
```

Build success and I copy OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/libs to android studio.

But when I compile my native code from Android studio,

```
Ptr<Stitcher> stitcher = Stitcher::create();
```

Sounds like above code line compile error:

```
error: undefined reference to 'cv::Stitcher::create(cv::Stitcher::Mode)'
```

Maybe Stitcher module missed from sdk  librarylibopencv_java4.so

How can I config the make file to include this module?

Answer (score 0):

To build only native library

```
export WORK_DIR=`pwd`
export ANDROID_SDK=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_NDK=$ANDROID_SDK/ndk-bundle
export OPENCV_ROOT= $WORK_DIR/../
cmake $OPENCV_ROOT -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$ANDROID_NDK/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=android-23 -DBUILD_JAVA=OFF -DBUILD_ANDROID_EXAMPLES=OFF -DBUILD_ANDROID_PROJECTS=OFF -DANDROID_STL=c++_shared -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=$WORK_DIR/out -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a
make
make install
```